# HTML2PDF margin bug

Tags: php, html, css, html2pdf

I am currently using html2pdf to convert a document in my company to PHP, to be able to include my variables afterwards and save it as a pdf,
the problem is currently with my "div M1,M2,M3".
I make it align with "#M1,#M2,#M3{display: inline;}"
however I feel that my M2 "TEL:" is based on the top frame, rather than on the M1

```
$html = '<img src="logoTCSfinal.png" class="tcs" style="width:10%;margin- 
left:20px;margin-right: 550px;">
<img src="ICSL.png" class="ics" style="width:10%;"><br>
<div style="width: 100%;padding-left:2px;padding-top:2px;font-weight: 600;padding- 
bottom:2px;border: 3px solid #000000; text-align: left;">DEFINITION DES BESOINS</div>
<style>#M1,#M2,#M3{display: inline;}</style>
<div id="M1" style="padding-left:5px;padding-top: 10px;font-weight: 600;">SOCIETE: 
</div>
<div id="M2" style="clear: both;font-weight: 600;">TEL:</div>
<div id="M3" style="font-weight: 600;">FAX:</div>';
$html2pdf = new Html2Pdf();
$html2pdf->writeHTML($html);
$html2pdf->output();
?>
```

but
however it displays it to me like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U48FB.png)

Comment: I don't know HTML2PDF, maybe try to add `padding-top` to all `#M1, #M2, #M3`? `Clear` do nothing since there are no floated elements.

Comment: with a padding-top on all my DIV's it shifts them well downwards but it doesn't fix the "TEL:" which is way too far to the right